# Does Canvas keep going if you leave the page?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Click this link, after around 2 seconds you will see some ships coming at you. Now go to a different window for like 15-20 seconds. then come back, you will see a huge wall of enimes coming at you. Now obviously this is because canvas keeps the loops going but is just not letting the came continue on?

So any help would be great, I know this is not an issue during gameplay but if anyone goes off the window then it kind of messes things up...

I tried to solve this by adding these listeners:

```
       window.onblur = function() {
            // Add logic to pause the game here...
            stopLoop();
        };

        window.onfocus = function() {
            // Add logic to pause the game here...
            startLoop();
        };
```

But it does not solve the issue...

The actual loops:

```
function init()
{

isPlaying = true;
drawBackground();
drawBars();
setUpListeners();
startLoop();

}
```

and then...

```
function Loop()
{
if (isPlaying == true)
{
Player1.draw();
requestAnimFrame(Loop);
 drawAllEnemies();

}

}

function startLoop()
{

isPlaying = true;
Loop();
startSpawningEnemies();

}

function stopLoop()
{
isPlaying = false;
stopSpawningEnemies();
}

function spawnEnemy(n) //total enemies starts at 0 and every-time you add to array
{
  for (var x = 0; x < n; x++)
   {

     enemies[totalEnemies] = new Enemy();
     totalEnemies++; 
   }

}

function drawAllEnemies()
{

  ClearEnemyCanvas();
  for(var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++)
   {
      enemies[i].draw();

   }
}

function startSpawningEnemies()
{
  stopSpawningEnemies();

  spawnInterval = setInterval(function() {spawnEnemy(spawnAmount);}, spawnRate); //this calls spawnEnemy every spawnRate
  /////////spawn 'spawnAmount' enemies every 2 seconds




}


function stopSpawningEnemies()
{

clearInterval(spawnInterval);
}
```

---

Actual methods for the enemy:

```
function Enemy()  //Object
{

//////Your ships values
this.EnemyHullMax = 1000;
this.EnemyHull = 1000;
this.EnemyShieldMax = 1000;
this.EnemyShield = 347;
this.SpaceCrystalReward = 2684;
this.EnemySpeed = 2; //should be around 6 pixels every-time draw is called by interval, directly linked to the fps global variable
////////////



////Pick Ship
this.type = "Hover";
this.srcX = EnemySrcXPicker(this.type);
this.srcY = EnemySrcYPicker(this.type);

this.enemyWidth = EnemyWidthPicker(this.type);
this.enemyHeight = EnemyHeightPicker(this.type);

this.drawX = EnemydrawXPicker(this.type);
this.drawY = EnemydrawYPicker(this.type);
////


}

Enemy.prototype.draw = function()
{

this.drawX -= this.EnemySpeed;
ctxEnemy.globalAlpha=1;
ctxEnemy.drawImage(spriteImage,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.enemyWidth,this.enemyHeight,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.enemyWidth,this.enemyHeight);

}


function EnemySrcXPicker(type)
{
if (type == "Hover")

    {

        return 906;
      }
}

function EnemySrcYPicker(type)
{
if (type == "Hover")

   {
        return 616;
     }
}

function EnemydrawXPicker(type)
{
if (type == "Hover")

     {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() *  1000) + canvasWidthEnemy;
     }
}

function EnemydrawYPicker(type)
{
if (type== "Hover")

     {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvasHeightEnemy - 72));
     }
}


function EnemyWidthPicker(type)
{
if (type == "Hover")

     {
        return 90;
     }
}

function EnemyHeightPicker(type)
{
if (type == "Hover")

     {

        return 72;
     }
}
```

Comment: Laving the page causes huge wall of enimes?

Comment: Do you define `spawnInterval` anywhere outside of `startSpawningEnemies()` or `stopSpawningEnemies()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the loop.

If you use setTimeOut or setInterval, then yes. The loop will continue even when the window loses focus.

If you use requestFrameAnimation, then no, the loop will stop when the window loses focus.

requestFrameAnimation was created to solve issues like this. Having you PC burn CPU cycles for something not active is just silly.

Comment: +1 requestAnimationFrame is definitely the way to go here. It might also be helpful to use the page visibility API to display a pause screen for games when they tab away and come back.